# Модуль Фейсбука блока кнопок «Поделиться» от Яндекса не всегда правильно извлекает данные со страницы, не смотря на правильную микроразметку

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

На моём сайте https://superbank.ru на некоторых страницах (не везде) при нажатии на кнопку Фейсбука подтягиваются неверные данные, не смотря на правильную микроразметку! В чём дело?

Это происходит только при использовании блока кнопок «Поделиться» от Яндекса.

При использовании других виджетов расшаривания в Фейсбук данные с этой же самой страницы берутся правильные!

Вот [адрес](https://superbank.ru/products/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%86-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%C2%AB%D0%91%D1%83%D1%82%D1%82-%D0%B8-%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BC%C2%BB%2C-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%C2%AB%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%C2%BB.html) страницы.

И это не одна такая страница: таких страниц на моём сайте множество.

Очевидно, что проблема кроется на стороне Яндекса, так как другие виджеты расшаривания в Фейсбук отрабатывают эти страницы корректно!

Вот, что подтягивает кнопка Яндекса «Поделиться в Фейсбуке»

[image: Подтягиваются неверные данные, не смотря на правильную микроразметку. Фотография вообще не подтягивается.]

А вот, что подтягивает другой виджет расшаривания в социальные сети, установленный на той же самой странице

[image: Вот так должно быть]